# Lower Bound on Decay of Convolution

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be $L^1$ functions.

**Theorem.** If $|f(x)| \leq |x|^{-a}$ and $|g(x)| \leq |x|^{-b}$ for all large $x$, where $a,b > 0$, then 
$$
|(f \ast g)(x)| \leq \int |f(y)g(x-y)| dy  \leq C|x|^{-a} + C|x|^{-b} \leq 2C\max\{|x|^{-a},|x|^{-b}\}  
$$
for all large $x$.

We give the proof here. But see also [Decay of Convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812798/decay-of-a-convolution).

\begin{align}
\int |f(y)g(x-y)| dy 
&= \int_{|y| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x|} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy + \int_{|y| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x|} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy \\
&= \int_{\substack{|y| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x| \\ }} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy + \int_{\substack{|y| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x| \\ |y-x| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x| }} |f(y)g(x-y)| dy \\
&\leq \int_{\substack{|y| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x| \\ }} |y|^{-a}g(x-y) dy + \int_{\substack{|y| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x| \\ |y-x| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x| }} f(y)|x-y|^{-b} dy \\
&\leq
2^a|x|^{-a} \| g \|_{1} + 2^b |y|^{-b} \| f \|_1 \\
\end{align}

The theorem says $(f \ast g)(x)$ decays at least at as fast as the slower of the functions $f$, $g$.

**Question.** Can $(f \ast g)(x)$ decay faster than the the slowest of $f$, $g$? For example, suppose we know that $|f(x)| \geq |x|^{-c}$ for infinitely many $x$ and $g$ is a Schwartz function. Is it possible to have 
$$
|(f \ast g)(x)| \leq C|x|^{-c}
$$ 
for all large $x$?

Comment: To help anyone reading your question: If $|y| \leq \frac{|x|}{2}$ then $|y-x|\geq |x|-|y| \geq |x| -\frac{|x|}{2}=\frac{|x|}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the convolution can involve cancellation that makes it a lot smaller than the larger of $f,g$. For example, let 
$$
F(x) = (x^2+1)^{-2}\sin(x^3), \quad f=F', \quad g(x) = \exp(-x^2)
$$
Note that $f(x)$ is often of size $\sim x^{-2}$ because it picks up the factor of $3x^2$ from the chain rule. On the other hand, 
$$f*g = F'*g = F*g' = O(x^{-4})$$
because both $F$ and $g'$ are $O(x^{-4})$ at infinity. This example can be amplified: more oscillation yields more cancellation in convolution.

Comment: For the convolution in the last paragraph of this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278988/decay-of-positive-definite-function-in-lp/279013#279013, why does it continue to fail to satisfy power bounds?